# C++ Stuck in infinite loop

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, infinite

Alright guys, I'm new to programming and need a little help. I have a program that takes a sentence that's entered and shows the number of words and vowels. I then want to repeat the program if the user wants so, but when I use the do-while loop, in gets stuck in an infinite loop. After I enter 'Y' to repeat, it loops back to show the vowels and number of words I entered for the previous sentence.

Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char sentence[50];
    int countA=0, countE=0, countI=0, countO=0, countU=0, countSP=0;
    char repeat;

    do {
    cout << "Enter sentence : ";
    cin.get(sentence, 50, '\n'); cin.ignore(10, '\n');


    cout << sentence;
    cout << "\nThird character is : " << sentence[2];
    cout << "\nLast character is : " << sentence[strlen(sentence)-1];
    cout << "\nLength of sentence is : " << strlen(sentence);

    for(int x=0; x < strlen(sentence); x++) {
        char ch = tolower (sentence[x]);
        switch (ch) {
        case 'a':   countA++;break;
        case 'e':   countE++;break;
        case 'i':   countI++;break;
        case 'o':   countO++;break;
        case 'u':   countU++;break;
        case ' ':   countSP++;break;
        }
    }


    cout << "\nNumber of A's : " << countA;
    cout << "\nNumber of E's : " << countE;
    cout << "\nNumber of I's : " << countI;
    cout << "\nNumber of O's : " << countO;
    cout << "\nNumber of U's : " << countU;
    cout << "\nNumber of words : " << countSP+1;

    cout << "\n\nWould you like to enter a new sentence? (Y/N): ";
    cin >> repeat;

    }while (repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y');

    _getche();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(repeat == 'y' && repeat == 'Y');` will *always* be false.  How can it equal both?

Comment: i think you mean `(repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y');`

Answer (score 3):

The expression `(repeat == 'y' && repeat == 'Y')` will *always* equal false, as `repeat` cannot be equal to both `'y'` *and* `'Y'`.

You might have meant:

```
(repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y');
```

Comment: Sorry yeah that was suppose to be 'or', I changed it when I was messing about with the code and forgot to change it back before I pasted it to this. It's when I have 'or' in that it's getting stuck in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Change `(repeat == 'y' && repeat == 'Y');` to `(repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y');`

EDIT:
You also have no braces to open or close your loop try this.

```
while (repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y')
   {
      _getche();
   }
```

because the loop has no body and it does not know what to execute.

EDIT2 why not do this?

```
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     do while (repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y') {
     Enter()
     cout << "\n\nWould you like to enter a new sentence? (Y/N): ";
     cin >> repeat;
}

}
return 0;

Enter(){
    char sentence[50];
    int countA=0, countE=0, countI=0, countO=0, countU=0, countSP=0;
    char repeat = Y;

cout << "Enter sentence : ";
cin.get(sentence, 50, '\n'); cin.ignore(10, '\n');


cout << sentence;
cout << "\nThird character is : " << sentence[2];
cout << "\nLast character is : " << sentence[strlen(sentence)-1];
cout << "\nLength of sentence is : " << strlen(sentence);

for(int x=0; x < strlen(sentence); x++) {
    char ch = tolower (sentence[x]);
    switch (ch) {
    case 'a':   countA++;break;
    case 'e':   countE++;break;
    case 'i':   countI++;break;
    case 'o':   countO++;break;
    case 'u':   countU++;break;
    case ' ':   countSP++;break;
    }



cout << "\nNumber of A's : " << countA;
cout << "\nNumber of E's : " << countE;
cout << "\nNumber of I's : " << countI;
cout << "\nNumber of O's : " << countO;
cout << "\nNumber of U's : " << countU;
cout << "\nNumber of words : " << countSP+1;

repeat = ' ';
}
```

Comment: Sorry yeah that was suppose to be 'or', I changed it when I was messing about with the code and forgot to change it back before I pasted it to this. It's when I have 'or' in that it's getting stuck in the loop.

Comment: But it's a do-while loop? The code to be executed comes after the do? The condition comes after the while, which is if repeat is equal to 'Y' or 'y'. No?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `repeat == 'y' && repeat == 'Y'` with `repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y')`, because the condition in your code can never be true.

Comment: Sorry yeah that was suppose to be 'or', I changed it when I was messing about with the code and forgot to change it back before I pasted it to this. It's when I have 'or' in that it's getting stuck in the loop.

Comment: When you say "infinite loop", what exactly is the code doing or not doing? Is it just going through the whole program again no matter what it is you type?

Comment: Basically, ill run the program, enter the sentence, it shows the vowels, words and then asks do I want to repeat. I enter 'Y', it then repeats the vowels and words from the sentence I first entered.

Comment: Please add that to your question. It is important information.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that now. Thanks.

Comment: From what I can tell, you should start by initializing the variables inside the do-while structure, rather than outside it.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix it either.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to remember is that C ++ does what is called **Short-Circuit evaluation.** If one side of the && condition is false, then *everything* is false. For an example,

```
int y = 1;
int x = 2;
if (y == 0 && x ==2) {
....
}
```

It is just going to check the first part. Since y = 1, it is going to return a false Boolean and this if statement will never be executed.

Like wise, with or, ||, if one side of the condition is true, then the condition will return a True Boolean and then the condition will be executed.

For your situation, the correct way to do this would be:

```
(repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y');
```

This way, if the first side is true, then the condition will be met and it will execute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `repeat` at the beginning of your loop to anything else than `Y` or `y` (e.g. : `repeat = NULL;`)

Comment: No joy, still getting stuck in the loop.

Comment: I am sorry, but if I compile your code with this extention (in Visual Studio 2012) , everything works fine. Maybe you could give us some more information?
(e.g.: compiler ,special settings you made in your project/compiler)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012, no special settings, they're just setup as standard. I've also tried it using Code::Blocks 12.11, but I'm having the same issue. Would you be able to show me your exact code?

Comment: Sure, it is just yours, but with one line added. You need to reset repeat, because cin will use the data,which is already stored in it, instead of reasking for an input, if repeat is not empty. Same counts for `char sentence[50];`.  
    
`int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])  
{  
      
    int countA=0, countE=0, countI=0, countO=0, countU=0, countSP=0;  
    char repeat;  
  
    do {  
 repeat = NULL; //added line  
 char sentence[50];  


    cout << "Enter sentence : ";  
    cin.get(sentence, 50, '\n'); cin.ignore(10, '\n');`

Comment: Oh I forgot that it would be better if you set `cin.ignore()` to flush your stream at the top of your loop:
`do{ cin.ignore();  
    cout << "Enter sentence: ";
 etc....}while (repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y');`

Comment: Thanks it's working for me now. It seems to be the cin.ignore(); that's fixing it for me. Thanks again, appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Would you mind of checking the question as answered by accepting the answer?